# How to use chinese chars in section names?

Tags: pdftex, texlive, cjk, chinese

This is how I (currently) embed chinese in my documents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
\tableofcontents
\section{abstract}
摘要
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But looks like this approach do not support chinese on section names:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
\tableofcontents
\section{摘要}
摘要
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

This returns the following error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character 摘 (U+6458)
(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 ...MessageBreak \DeclareUnicodeCharacter }}{1}
```

So what can I do in order to use chinese in section names which appear on the toc?

Comment: An option is using `ctexart` class. Another is using XeLaTeX. These are options, not direct solutions to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `.toc` file is written *after* `\end{CJK}` and LaTeX no longer knows about Chinese characters.

Just use the “free form” for `CJK`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}

\CJK{UTF8}{gbsn}

\tableofcontents

\section{摘要}
摘要

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also found xeCJK with XeLaTeX works (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Chinese) with the advantage there is no need for something like `\CJK{UTF8}{gbsn}`, wondering if is time to take xelatex more seriously.

Comment: @KcFnMi For Chinese, I think you should.